# Linux WGET -O command for non existing folders?

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I can't `wget` while there is no path already to save. I mean, `wget` doens't work for the non-existing paths. For e.g:

```
wget -O /path/to/image/new_image.jpg http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg
```

If `/path/to/image/` is not previously existed, it always returns:

```
No such file or directory
```

How can i make it work?

Comment: Oh, you need the non-existential version... it can download things to places that don't exist!  Of course, you'll need a non-existential version of ls to see them though.

Comment: **Do not use `-O <new file>`**. Instead use `--directory-prefix <new dir>` as @SivakumarManickam suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dir manually before run with

```
mkdir -p /path/to/image/
```

Or even write function that will do it itself and put it in ~/.bashrc or whatever shell you use:

```
wget_mkdir() {
    mkdir -p $2
    wget $@
}
```

don't forget to add it to current session with `. ~/.bashrc`

Or even just run in the shell

```
function wget_mkdir() { mkdir -p ${2%/*} ; wget $@ ; }
```

and start use it immediately as:

```
wget_mkdir -O /path/to/image/new_image.jpg http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your looking for "--directory-prefix=prefix" ... if so try as

wget --directory-prefix=/path/to/image/ http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg